# Целесообразно ввести метку "речевая недостаточность"

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, метки

Речевая недостаточность является причиной значительного числа речевых ошибок, допускаемых носителями русского языка. Для того, чтобы исправить ошибку, нужно правильно ее квалифицировать. Метка содержит косвенную подсказку, направляя мысль редактирующего при исправлении дефектных фраз. Слишком общие метки могут увести в сторону, стать источником ошибочных вариантов исправления. В этом я уже имел возможность убедиться. Отсутствие метки "речевая недостаточность" тем более нелогично, что логически соотносительная с ней  метка "речевая избыточность" имеется.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на то, что метки создаются самими пользователями, когда возникает необходимость. Привилегия, позволяющая делать это, автоматически выдается по достижении 150 баллов репутации.

Подробнее — в Справке: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags.

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение.